# Change path separator on NodeJs

Tags: node.js, path, gruntjs

I'm using grunt-bbb-styles to process my css files

My css is like this

```
body {
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
  background: url("../images/outer_bg.jpg") repeat;
}
```

after bbb-styles executes it became

```
body {letter-spacing: -0.3px; background: url("/app\images\outer_bg.jpg") repeat;}
```

See the backslash.

It fails loading on the browser

I'm using windows 8

It happens on path.join()

Is it possible to set path.sep globally for nodeJs?

regards

Answer (score 0):

Changing path.sep doesn't change the behaviour of the path functions.
Different versions of the path module are exported depending on which system the process is running on.

e.g. this is the posix implementation of path.join, note the hardcoded separator:

```
function () {
  var paths = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  return exports.normalize(paths.filter(function(p, index) {
    if (typeof p !== 'string') {
      throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.join must be strings');
    }
    return p;
  }).join('/'));
}
```

The issue has to be fixed in the grunt-bbb-styles module, so submitting a issue or a pull request is the best solution.